# Avid Sibelius on macOS Sierra - linking folders

Tags: macos, symlink

Notational software Avid Sibelius installs preferences into the following path: `/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Avid`

That folder contains House Styles, Keyboard Shortcuts, Plug-ins and everything else one needs to professionally use the software.

I would like to have an automatic backup (or synchronisation) of this folder in a **non-library** folder. 
My intent is to have it **mirrored** to `iCloudDrive`so that it gets automatically backed up and I may be able to just copy-paste it into a new installation on a new machine should the need arise.

Any idea on how to obtain this? 
Thanks

Comment: How is Time Machine *not* already accomplishing the task of backing this up?

Comment: Very good point, but this is really the weak spot!  If I would like to restore from a Time Machine backup (that is, all of the system) that would work but, if I had to only browse for that specific folder, I could not access the Library from Time Machine. Hence, I would like it to be copied also somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a short script (even a single line command would work) to make a dupe of the files to your iCloud folder

Your iCloud folder is found locally on your machine in `/Users/< username >/Library/Mobile\ Documents`

(replace < username > with your actual username and be certain to notice the backslash before the space in "Mobile Documents")

If you want to avoid having to preface a backslash before (a.k.a "escaping") the space, put the whole line in quotes:

```
"/Users/Library/< username >/Mobile Documents/foo.bar"
```

I would use `tar` to create a single file archive and `gzip` to compress it to save space.  The command below will accomplish both:

```
$ tar cvfz "/Users/username/Library/Mobile Documents/Avid_Backup.tgz" "/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Avid"
```

You could then use Automator to run a shell script executing the command at a predetermined interval (Automator Calendar Alarm)

[image]

Comment: The total size of the folder would be about 40MB so maybe ZIP is not vital but I will try it at once. Btw, I have always wondered what tar.gz files were. When new versions of Sibelius are issued they are always sent as .dmg if one wants to install them from zero or in tar.gz if one just wants to run the software.

Comment: I have followed your instructions in Terminal, it did something but then I don't find the created archive. Also Spotlight doesn't find `Avid_Backup.tgz`. What did I miss?

Comment: `tar` = "tape archive"; `gz` = gzip archive.  `tgz` = "gziped tar  archive".

Comment: check your icloud...  also try using the command in Terminal first to make sure it works.

Comment: Checked iCloud, there is nothing; used the command in Terminal, it does perform some action but then in iCloud I have nothing created; tried with Automator and it throws me an Error.

Comment: Maybe there should already be a folder called Avid_Backup? Did I have to create it?

Comment: There is still something not working. Nothing is getting created where it should. Any idea why?

Comment: When you execute the command in Terminal, what error message are you getting?

Comment: No error... I get a list of operations which begin with the letter `a` and that are followed by file paths (each corresponding to a file in the directory I want to be copied). When the whole process ends I go to my iCloud folder and there is no `Avid_Backup` archive created. If I ask Spotlight to find it there is no result... now the task gets properly executed without errors in Automator it again, nothing is created...

Comment: Where am not clear?  run this in *Terminal*

Comment: I am sorry... I am copy-pasting it into terminal, changing `username` to my username as written in the Home directory and pressing Enter... am not experienced enough to change your instructions...

Comment: When I paste your line of code without changing username Terminal gives me this error: `tar: Failed to open '/Users/username/Library/Mobile Documents/Avid_Backup.tgz'`

Comment: Ok, I think I got somewhere. I tried to save the archive to the `Downloads` folder instead of the `iCloud folder` and it worked. Now, I would really like to understand why the `tar command` would not have access into the `Mobile Documents`
 directory. Any idea?

Comment: You're having issues with the spaces in the directory name.  I made some additions to the answer which should solve your problem.

Comment: The true issue seems to be the direct path to iCloud Drive. After `/Mobile\ Documents/` one has to add `com~apple~CloudDocs` . In this way the `tar cvfz` command from you proposed @Allan functions perfectly! I wonder if that is because I have enabled Documents and Desktop in the Cloud on macOS Sierra or if that is what it should have always been.

Comment: `com~apple~CloudDocs` is just a folder - you could have named it anything you wanted.  I tested without a folder and it worked fine.

Comment: I am sure it work for you, I simply wonder why for my the `Mobile Documents` didn’t work and the other did. I suspect it has something to do with Documents in the Cloud. Do you have this option activated or not? Thanks